# Java need explanation on my Lexicographic order algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringOrder
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s1, s2, s3;
        Scanner keyboard = new Keyboard(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your first string.");
        s1 = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your second string.");
        s2 = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your third string.");
        s3 = keyboard.next();
        int c1 = abs(s1.compareTo(s2));
        int c2 = abs(s2.compareTo(s3));
        int c3 = abs(s1.compareTo(s3));
        System.out.println(Math.min(c1,c2,c3)+" "+Math.median(c1,c2,c3)+" "+Math.max(c1,c2,c3));
        System.out.println("lexicographical sorting finished");
    }
}
```

The above is my code.

I have no problem with the code itself.

I am just trying to see if this way of me trying to solve this problem is true.

I am trying to sort the three user-input string values into *Lexicographic order*.

I came up with the solution to use the `compareTo` method and store the resulting values into integer variables, then use absolute value to find which one is next to each other.

I have not compiled the code above yet.

My only question is whether should my algorithm works or not?
I 'm trying to figure out the algorithm on my own, so I wouldn't want any preferred solutions to the problem, but just an explanation of why it shouldn't work or should work.

Comment: 1. Compile it. 2. Experiment with running it. 3. If you can't figure out why it behaves the way it does, use a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compareTo`'s only guarantee is about the sign of the result (0, >0, <0), not its size. So using it "to find which one is next to each other" just won't work.

Comment: I thought compareTo generates the difference between to strings' unicode values. Well i guess i've got to compile it